# Is it required to clear the buffer before drawing in DirectX?

Tags: directx

I'm new using DirectX. Is it required to clear the targetview everytime I do BeginDraw()?

```
renderTarget.BeginDraw();
renderTarget.Clear(colorBlack); //required? 
// Draw elements
renderTarget.EndDraw();
swapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);
```

If I want to keep elements in my scene and draw new ones in the next flip, do I need to redraw all of them or can I keep the previous ones?

Comment: If you don't need to redraw the whole screen, then don't. No, it is not required, it is just useful to blank the canvas.

Comment: Note that depending on the graphics hardware and architecture, it can make a big performance difference to fully clear the render target vs. leaving the previous frame data on it.  So, it's not required if you are guaranteed to draw the entire render target, but might be worth doing anyway. As with all things performance, measure it both ways.